# File Upload not working, when Flow is called via URL in Salesforce1 App

Tags: salesforce1-app, visual-workflow, fileupload

We have created a flow screen to upload a file. As per our requirement, Flow will be called via URL from a Lightning component. It works fine for Desktop.

But, the file upload is not working in the Salesforce1 App.

Note: The same flow works when invoked from a quick action in both Desktop & Mobile.

Please let me know your suggestions to fix this issue.